# TCP Debug Error C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

```
public Server([Optional, DefaultParameterValue(0x6c1)] int port, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("127.0.0.1")] string ip)
{
    this.IP = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    this.Port = port;
    this.listenerConnection = new TcpListener(this.IP, this.Port);
    this.listenerConnection.Start();
    this.listenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.listen));
    this.listenerThread.Start();
}
```

is the code I have, it runs fine but when I debug it, I get the message:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: port

Can anyone help?

Comment: and what is the value of Port you give at debug time? Can you tell?

Comment: what is the type of this.Port? what is the value? Port ranges for TCP are from 0 to 65535

Comment: Off topic: just FYI the DefaultParameterValue 0x6c1 is decimal 1729

Comment: Is this a Ramanujan reference?

Comment: I've not heard of Ramanuajan references

Comment: Apparently you find them on taxicabs. ps I didn't know about Ramanujan either. +1 I learned something

Answer (score 2):

Well, then `port` is out of the range of valid values, which is between [IPEndPoint.MinPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.minport.aspx) and [IPEndPoint.MaxPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.maxport.aspx).

Comment: the port I'm using is 1274, I know it's correct because it worked on my VPS before.

Comment: @Neel: that can't be. Set a breakpoint before `this.listenerConnection = new TcpListener(this.IP, this.Port);` and watch the variable `this.Port`.

Comment: @Neel is there something else using TCP port 1274 on your computer? Run netstat -a

Comment: I set a breakpoint and I get the error "The requested address is not valid in its context" at listenerConnection.Start();

Comment: @kcsavage: that won't throw an exception until calling `Start()` on the `TcpListener`. The [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6z86e63.aspx) has just two exceptions, one of which is an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on `port` and the other one doesn't really matter here. Edit: @Neel: please provide the values of both parameters.

Comment: @kcsavage: A port in use should not throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` though. I wonder what comes from CodeCaster's comment - I doubt that trying to inspect `this.Port` actually gave that error?

Comment: The error @Neel received about context points to that IP not being valid on his machine. Can you ping that address @Neel?

Comment: pinged it and it's fine, gah it doesn't work with the ip and it doesn't work with localhost. I'm completely stumped. /wrists

Comment: Again, set a breakpoint where you create the TcpListener and post the values of `this.IP` and `this.Port`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the IPAddress of your machine? You can use the following code to obtain the IPAddress of the machine you are running the application on:

```
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress localIpAddress = null;

forach(IPAddress address in host.AddressList)
{
    if(address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
          localIpAddress = address;
    }
}

TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localIpAddress, port);
listener.Start();
```

Additionally, you may want to consider using a default port > 5000.  As there are many ports between 0 and 5000 that are reserved or already use by services.